# Infopath webpart always opening a new Form

Tags: 2010, infopath

I customized a my List form in infopath designer and created a new view for the form.

Than i created a new webpart page named Test.aspx and added an infopath webpart on it.

I selected the list and my newly created view in edit mode.

Later on i tried the following the URL in the browser :
http://test.com/site pages/test.aspxList=cc378f5f-0de9-46e5-a562-4e9a69065cf2&ID=83

Page opened with an empty infopath form. When i saved it a new item got created in the list.

I want to open the form in edit mode. Could someone please suggest what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to set rules in you InfoPath form.  By adding rules you can then get your form to display different views depending on field values.  I have just done this very thing today.

http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2011/11/infopath-2010-one-form-multiple-views/

Hope this helps.  Helped me out.  But trust me, from what your question reads - this is your solution!